# Reusing a batch multiple times - TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, bayesian

I have an interesting problem that I would like to solve.

So I have a DCNN that has dropout, which is generally only used during training. But what I want to do, is to apply the dropout during the test phase as well.

Now this is easily done once per batch, but now I want to do the same thing N times per batch, where at step, the dropped neurons will change.

The goal is to sample the network using dropout, to get a feeling of its certainty. Here is a pseudo code of what I'm thinking

```
def test():
# Get shuffle_batch
features, labels, nBatchesPerEpoch = get_feature_and_labels(batchSize=10)

isTraining = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=(), name='isTraining')
dropOut = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=(), name='dropout')

# Create network
neuralNet = DCNN(features,labels,dropout,isTraining)

# Output from neural net
logits = neuralNet.logits

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Loop through whole batch
    for _ in range(nBatchesPerEpoch):

        # Here do some fancy stuff so that the same minibatch is used, but dropouts change
        logits_sum = 0.0
        for _ in range(20): # Do 20 samples from each minibatch
            logits_sum += sess.run(logits,feed_dict={isTraining: True, dropOut:0.5}

        # Then here I work with the generated logits
        DoSomeStuff(logits_sum/20)
```

Hope I'm making myself clear enough :)

A direction I think might be of interest is using tf.identity?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you are after, but in my experiments, I load a batch of features and labels, then use it in sess.run() to run the model, and then use the same batch to actually check what elements got activated/etc. So, technically, I call sess.run() on the same batch more than once at each step, and seems like without causing TF to reload it. So why won't you be able to just run the model several times with the same batch, just serving the different dropout rate?

Comment: Hmm, so you mean that I should fetch the batch via sess.run, then use it via feed dict to the network? I guess that should work, need to change my layout a bit though :)

Comment: yes, once you fetch it, i think it becomes a numpy array, so you can re-use it: feature_batch, label_batch = sess.run([features, labels])

            _ = sess.run([train_step], feed_dict={X: feature_batch, Y_: label_batch, keep_prob: dropout})

                guessY = tf.argmax(Y, 1).eval({X: feature_batch})
                trueY = tf.argmax(label_batch, 1).eval()

Comment: to technically, in the above i used both the features batch and the labels batch twice in the same step. Seems to work for me...

Comment: Sounds reasonable enough, thanks for the suggestion! :)